# Sharing audio file in downloads folder with FileProvider

Tags: java, android

**I want to share the sounds in my downloads folder on whatsapp but it says sharing failed please try again.**

**My Manifest.xml**

```
        <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="appid.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

**my provider_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path
    name="external_files"
    path="." />
<external-files-path
    name="external_files"
    path="." />
<!-- FOR SD CARD-->
<root-path
    name="sdcard1"
    path="." />
</paths>
```

**my codes**
I'm getting the path to the file
ı am creating a new sound
And I'm trying to share that voice
androidOnDaPaylas(soundName); //String

```
    public void androidOnDaPaylas(String soundName) { 
    Uri uricik = null;
    File soundPath = newFile(mCoontext.getExternalFilesDir
    (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath());
    File newFile = new File(soundPath,soundName);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        uricik = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Objects.requireNonNull(mCoontext),
                "appid.fileprovider", (newFile));
    }
    Intent compartirAudio = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    compartirAudio.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    compartirAudio.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    compartirAudio.setType("audio/*");
    compartirAudio.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uricik);
    mCoontext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(compartirAudio, "Share"));

}
```

Comment: Add a statement `if (!newFile.exists()) { Toast (....sorry file does not exits newFile.getAbsolutePath());  return;}`

Comment: Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS is my download folder  and witch path should ı use

Comment: No. `mCoontext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` is your download folder. To see full path have a look at `soundPath.getAbsolutePath()`. Now i already asked you for two full paths. I expect you to add the exists() check too.

Comment: it says there is a no folder

Comment: Which folder? Edit your code here so it represents your new code. So we can also see that message.

Comment: getPath and getAbsolutePath() is giving to me same path (/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/appidi/files/Download)